# ActionCable.Connection state not set to "open" on successful connection, causes send method to fail

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

#### Relevant Info about Environment

- Rails Version: 5.2
- Devise Authentication

#### Code

Warden hooks for setting cookies

```
# config/initializers/warden_hooks.rb
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = user.id
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = 30.minutes.from_now
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = nil
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = nil
end
```

Connection parent class for authenticating. This works as it should and the connection is logged.

```
# application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
    end

    protected

    USER_CLASSES = ['admin', 'agent', 'tech', 'client']

    def find_verified_user
      user_class = USER_CLASSES.find { |klass| cookies.signed["#{klass}.id"] }
      user_id = cookies.signed["#{user_class}.id"]
      verified_user = User.find_by(id: user_id)

      if verified_user && cookies.signed["#{user_class}.expires_at"] > Time.now
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Client side code for setting up connection and sending messages.

```
// channels/conversations.js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  var messages = $('#messages');
  var projectId = messages.data('project-id');
  var button = $('#new_message input[type=submit]');
  var subscription = { channel: "ConversationsChannel", id: projectId };

  App.conversation = App.cable.subscriptions.create(subscription, {
    connected: function() {
      console.log('Upgraded to websocket connection.');
    },
    disconnected: function() {
      console.log('Websocket not connected.');
    },
    received: function(data) {
      messages.append(data['message']);
    },
    sendMessage: function(message, project_id) {
      return this.perform('send_message', {
        message: message,
        project_id: projectId
      });
    }
  });

  $('#message_body').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var message = e.target.value;

    if ($.trim(message).length > 0) {
      button.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      button.prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });

  $('#new_message').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var textarea = $('#message_body');

    App.conversation.sendMessage(textarea.val(), projectId);

    textarea.val('');
    button.prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

#### Problem

The connection is registered on the server

[image]

but the state of the `ActionCable.Connection` on the client is never set to open, which causes the `Connection.send` method to fail because `this.isOpen()` returns false (so the client is never subscribed to the channel) - [ActionCable source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable/connection.coffee#L16)

If I put a break point in chrome inside `send` and pass the data to the `webSocket.send` method the subscription is successful.

[image]

[image]

I have to repeat that again if I want to send a message, as the state of the connection is still not set to open even after successfully establishing the subscription.

#### What I've Already Tried

- Authenticating everyone
- Returning the `current_user` in `Connection#connect`
- Removing all code from the Connection class so no behavior is overridden

Comment: were you able to solve it?